# add last user IP in view

Tags: views, users

How to add last IP address for online user ( only last IP address ) and link to ban user IP address ?

i tried display all ip address but that showed to me all ip addresses from any time

i want show last ip address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it needs lots of coding and building a new module I only give you the tips and the algorithm, you need to know how to build a module.

1. build a module and create a variable (called IP) using `drupal_get_variable`, in this way a variable will be created in the `variable`` table.
2. for any user who visits your website, replace its IP address with the existing one (`drupal_set_variable`) in the IP variable (so far it is easy to implement).
3. you need output this variable in your `view`, so use the `hook_views_prebuild ($view)` hook function, get the IP and embed it in the view.